# How to make k8s microservice hostname generic with respect to namespace

Tags: kubernetes

Currently our k8s project has following use case were the namespaces are hardcoded into the values.yaml and application source codes

```
(apps) namespace - NS1                 

> micro-service-A1

> micro-service-A2

> micro-service-A3

(database) namespace - DB1

> mongo-service

(messaging) namespace - MB1

> kafka-zk-service
```

We want to run multiple sets of above services(apps, database, messaging) in unique namespaces defined by each Engineer(Developer)
 such that each developer can safely bring down/play-around changing  the complete set belonging to him without worrying impact on other Developers' namespace.

**# Developer1 (set)**

---

```
(apps) namespace - Dev1   

> micro-service-A1

> micro-service-A2

> micro-service-A3

(database) namespace - Dev1_DB

> mongo-service

(messaging) namespace - Dev1_MB

> kafka-zk-service
```

**# Developer2 (set)**

---

```
(apps) namespace - Dev2                

> micro-service-A1

> micro-service-A2

> micro-service-A3

(database) namespace - Dev2_DB

> mongo-service

(messaging) namespace - Dev2_MB                     

> kafka-zk-service
```

What should be the configuration of the yamls & application source code such that dynamic deployment is feasible in any namespace of developers choice?

Comment: Environment variables to parameterize the code and/or use a discovery service system like Eureka?

Comment: use a [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/)

Comment: Use Helm to deploy your services it makes your life alot easier all you have to do is make different values.yaml file depending on namespace e.g values.dev.yaml, values.staging.yaml

Comment: @MohsinAmjad still there is hard coded namespace in the application code say "application.properties" for a java service.

Comment: Most language runtimes do in fact have some sort of configuration file library, or way to access environment variables, or a unified configuration library, and replacing your hard-coded host names with configuration would be the right answer here.  This can't be done without changing your application source code, though.  What language and library stack are you using?  What problems have you encountered trying to make this value configurable?

Comment: It seems a bit complicated. If you don't want to hard code the namespace, the DNS must know `which domain` and `who ask` both (when query comes from namespace A, DNS should answer with record in namespace A first).

Comment: @BhavaniPrasad please let me know if any of the answers resolved your concerns.

Comment: @DawidKruk Jonas solution is working fine. Use service with External Name to resolve the namespace constraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Externalize configuration

It is good to *externalize your configuration* so that you can use a different configuration without building a new image.

Use a ConfigMap for configuration with address e.g. to other services or databases. See [DNS for Services and Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) for adressing.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: config
data:
  SERVICE_A: service-a.a-namespace.svc.cluster.local
  SERVICE_B: service-b.b-namespace.svc.cluster.local
  DB: db.local
```

Use the values from your ConfigMap as *environment variables* in your app by mapping it in your `Pod` or `Deployment` in the PodTemplate

```
  containers:
    - name: app-container
      image: k8s.gcr.io/app-image
      env:
        - name: SERVICE_A_ADDRESS
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: config
              key: SERVICE_A
        - name: SERVICE_B_ADDRESS
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: config
              key: SERVICE_B
```

### Service with External Name

If you want to move a service to a new namespace but keep the addressing, you can leave a [Service with External Name](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname)

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: service-a
  namespace: namespace-a
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: service-c.namespace-c.svc.cluster.local
  ports:
  - port: 80
```

Comment: This works fine and I am able to deploy the service in a different namespaces without modifying the namespace in the source code. Is there any way that charts can read the namespace that they are being deployed? So that I can update the service and configmap yaml files to take the namespace dynamically

Answer (score 0):

You can use `--namespace` flag to pass the namespace while applying the config instead of hard coding it in the config file.

`kubectl apply -f service.yml --namespace=test`

`kubectl apply -f service.yml --namespace=prod`

In this way, you can use the same config file to create the service resource in different namespaces.

Comment: But the namespaces ("redbus") are already hard coded in the application source code.  If I deploy the service with a different namespace, deployment will be successful but service is unable to resolve the hostname since it contains "redbus" hardcoded in source code.